# Load .csv file to dataframe in Scala for analysis

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a 100,000 line csv file that I need to load to a dataframe in scala.  It has a header row, only one worksheet and five columns.  I am new to using scala and IntelliJ and I would appreciate any help that I can get on this.

Comment: the csv file is on my desktop

Comment: Google spark read csv spark scala

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code that you can use to load CSV. you can add more options based on your need.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object LoadCsv extends App{

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Load CSV")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

 val csvSchema = StructType(Array(
     StructField("col1", StringType),
     StructField("col2", DateType),
     StructField("col3", DoubleType),
     StructField("col4", DateType),
     StructField("col5", DoubleType)
   ))

   spark.read
     .schema(csvSchema)
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("sep", ",")
    .csv("path to csv on itellij")
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting the following errors on the last line because I placed the path to the file that is on my desktop in the double quotes:          Cannot resolve overloaded method 'csv'                                                                     Wrong string literal

Comment: I was able to get rid of the errors by modifying the import....sql.types.  I still have 5 warnings.  When I run the code, I still get : Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: illegal access error create breakpoint